# Filter products by price range using WooCommerce wc_get_products

Tags: woocommerce

I'm getting a bunch of paginated variable products using [wc_get_products()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query). And I would like to only get products in a given price-range. The problem is that there are a lot of products, so only 20 products are fetched at a time.

According to the documentation, there are no `meta_query()`-option when using `wc_get_products()`.

So how do I get this?

Here is my current query:

```
$products_query = [
    'category' => [ get_queried_object()->slug ],
    'limit' => 20,
    'paginate' => true,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
];

$products = wc_get_products( $products_query );
```

Now remember, that it's something that needs to be implemented before the products are queried from the database.
Let's say that I have 100 products total. Since the products are paginated, then if I have ordered the products after `_price` (ASC), then page 1 should return the 20 cheapest products. And page 3 should return the products 40-60 (after they have been sorted).

---

### Solution attempts

**Attempt 1 - Try using a meta_query anyways**

I figured that wc_get_products was inspired and built on top of WP_Query, so I tried this:

```
$products_query = [
    'category' => [ get_queried_object()->slug ],
    'limit' => 20,
    'paginate' => true,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => 100,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ]
    ]
];

$products = wc_get_products( $products_query );
```

It just ignores the `meta_query`-part and returns a result as if it wasn't there.

---

**Attempt 2 - Using WP_Query**

Everywhere I look, there are arrows pointing towards `wc_get_products` and away from `wp_query`.
So I haven't pursued this.

---

**Attempt 3 - Raw SQL**

One solution would be to make a raw SQL-query. But since the products are variable products, then the SQL-query would be quite a few joins, since it should first find all products - and then find all variations. And then sort the products after the lowest variation-price (if the price-sort is ascending) - and after the highest variation-price (if the price-sort is descending). It's obviously possible, but I was hoping to find a more WordPress-like solution. And I'm not good at SQL.

---

**Attempt 4 - Using a plugin**

I look around a bit - and sort'n'filter-plugins for WooCommerce are *monsters*, since they slab scripts and styles left, right and center. So this seems like a poor solution.

---

**Attempt 5 - Using WooCommerce API**

I can see that `min_price` and `max_price` are mentioned under [List all products](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products). So this might actually work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variable products are something complicated to filter by price… So the following is not perfect, but show you a way to enable a price range in `WC_Product_Query`.

So the following function will **enable a custom price range query** on `WC_Product_Query`:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_price_range_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_price_range_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['price_range'] ) ) {
        $price_range = explode( '|', esc_attr($query_vars['price_range']) );

        if ( is_array($price_range) && count($price_range) == 2 ) {
            $query['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';

            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => reset($price_range), // From price value
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
            );

            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => end($price_range), // To price value
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
            );

            $query['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; // sort by price
            $query['order'] = 'ASC'; // In ascending order
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**EXAMPLE USAGE**

- Handle float numbers.
- The 1st price is separated from the 2nd one by a pipe `|`

Here we query products from $10.25 to $50 *(price range)*:

```php
$products = wc_get_products( [
    'limit'       => 20,
    'status'      => 'publish',
    'price_range' => '10.25|50', // The first price is separated from the 2nd one with a pipe
] );

echo '<ul>';

foreach( $products as $product ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">'.$product->get_name().' '.$product->get_price_html().'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

To filter **only variable products**, you can add the following line to the query:

```
    'type'        => 'variable',
```

**Documentation:** [wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

---

##### Optimized code version:

*(thanks to [@ChadReitsma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6280535/chad-reitsma))*

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_price_range_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_price_range_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['price_range'] ) ) {
        $price_range = explode( '|', esc_attr($query_vars['price_range']) );

        if ( is_array($price_range) && count($price_range) == 2 ) {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => $price_range, // Price range array
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
            );
            $query['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; // sort by price
            $query['order'] = 'ASC'; // In ascending order
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I can see `DECIMAL(10,3)` works better for float values like prices

Comment: @kanlukasz I am not dealing with price decimals in that answer, I just use a pipe to separate a price range (with or without decimals  as they are float numbers).

Comment: Your query can be improved by using the comparison: "BETWEEN" with the value: array($price_range[0], $price_range[1]),   Instead of two "AND" statements.

Comment: There is now an index table that contains the min and max price, would this query use this index?

Comment: The product_meta_lookup table https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7bfef28ac5d614837e696852ab4ffb8d7686a847/plugins/woocommerce/src/Blocks/QueryFilters.php#L79

Comment: This provided link is used for Blocks, so not for WC_Product_Query.

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7bfef28ac5d614837e696852ab4ffb8d7686a847/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php#L666

According to this we could just do `$_GET['min_price'] = 10; $_GET['max_price'] = 100;` but it would only work for the main query, it probably can be taken as inspiration to create our own filter, it's a bit stupid they didn't just add `min_price` and `max_price` as query vars so it could have been added direclty to the options of wc_get_products

Answer (score 0):

```
function handle_custom_query($query, $query_vars)
{
  if (!empty($query_vars['meta_query'])) {
    foreach ($query_vars['meta_query'] as $q) {
      $query['meta_query'][] = $q;
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query', 10, 3);
```

usage:

```
$query = new \WC_Product_Query(
  array(
    // ...standard queries
    // https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

    'meta_query'     => array(
      // ...array of meta queries
    ),

  )
);
$products = $query->get_products();
```